# How to create a graph with equal spacing between the xtics in gnuplot?

Tags: gnuplot

I am trying to recreate [this plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5hF1H.jpg)(the second image in the album) in gnuplot, and I am having trouble with reproducing the scale they are using on the x-axis. This code is my progress thus far:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/gnuplot
reset

# set svg output
set terminal svg size 410,250 fname 'Verdana, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif' \
fsize '9' rounded dashed
set output 'out.svg'

set xlabel 'x axis label'
set ylabel 'y axis label'
set xrange [0:200000]
set yrange [0:30000]

set xtics (\
'0' 0, '10K' 10000 ,'50K' 50000, '100K' 100000, '200K' 200000)
set ytics 2000



plot 'data.dat'  using 1:2 t 'Example line' w lp ls 1, \
     ''                  u 1:3 t 'Another example' w lp ls 2
```

where the file `data.dat` contains

```
# x y1  y2
10000 4000 8000
50000 6000 10000
100000 8000 12000
200000 10000 14000
```

The above results in [this graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5hF1H.jpg)(the first image).
As can be observed, the spacing between the labels on the x-axis are non-equal. But I would like them to be equal, like they are on the graph I showed in the beginning. Is it possible to reproduce that effect in gnuplot?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since that is not a linear nor logarithmic scale you will need something like this to do the trick (`using 0:2` uses 1,2,3... as x coordinates)

```
set xtics ('0' 0, '10K' 1 ,'50K' 2, '100K' 3, '200K' 4)
plot 'data.dat'  using 0:2 t 'Example line' w lp ls 1, \
     ''                  u 0:3 t 'Another example' w lp ls 2
```